# android quiz application implementation

Tags: android-file

iam currently working on an android general quiz application,the application has three categories of questions physics,chemistry and maths.
These topics are also further divided into several sub topics(displayed in a listview), like physics is again divided into topics like geophysics,astrophysics, solid state physics etc.
Each topics gives questions related to that topic.
On clicking on any topic gets you to a screen which has a grid view with question numbers and questions you have answered in dark blue colour and not answered in light blue colour.On clicking the grid element you can directly move on to the specified question.The question has answers as multiple choices.The user need to choose any of it and it will indicate whether it is right or wrong.(and also mark that question as attended).

But iam having doubts on certain areas of code:

1) How to save the questions,options...?(if it has to be done by using files please provide me some sample codes thankyou)

2) Sometimes the questions and options show up some images how to handle this..?(this only happens in some cases so that all the other times the image has to be set null)

3) How can I access questions ,options from the file in which it has been saved.(I need also display the images if any present .

Please do reply

Comment: You are asking a lot!

Comment: please tell me something about it @RobertMoskal